# JavaScript display new page when submit HTML form

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose I have 2 html files: form.html and confirm.html

form.html just have a text field and a submit button, when you hit submit it will display what you just typed in text field.

```
    <HTML>
      <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Test</TITLE>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 

        function display(){ 
            document.write("You entered: " + document.myform.data.value);
        } 
        </script> 
      </HEAD>
      <BODY>
      <center>    
<form name="myform">

  <input  type="text" name="data">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="display()">

</form>
    </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

Now I want that when hit submit button it will display entered value in confirm.html. What should I do? I mean what should be in confirm.html and how data from form.html be used in other location, do I need create a separate JavaScript file to store JS function so I can use it in both 2 html files. I am kind of new to all kind of stuff.

Note: No PHP or server side language or anything super here, just 2 html files in my Desktop and I want to test using FireFox.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using `localStorage` or `cookies`. Check one of the 2 solutions found below...

**1 -** If you have HTML5, you can store the content of you `input` into the `localStorage`.

**Try this example:**

`form.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        // Called on form's `onsubmit`
        function tosubmit() {
            // Getting the value of your text input
            var mytext = document.getElementById("mytext").value;

            // Storing the value above into localStorage
            localStorage.setItem("mytext", mytext);

            return true;
        }

    </script> 
</head>
<body>
    <center>   
        <!-- INLCUDING `ONSUBMIT` EVENT + ACTION URL --> 
        <form name="myform" onsubmit="tosubmit();" action="confirm.html">

            <input  id="mytext" type="text" name="data">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">

        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

`confirm.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

    // Called on body's `onload` event
    function init() {
        // Retrieving the text input's value which was stored into localStorage
        var mytext = localStorage.getItem("mytext");

        // Writing the value in the document
        document.write("passed value = "+mytext);
    }

</script>
</head>    

<body onload="init();">

</body>

</html>
```

---

**2 -** Also, as @apprentice mentioned, you can also use cookies with HTML standards.

**Try this example:**

`form.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Function for storing to cookie
        function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
        {
            var exdate=new Date();
            exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
            var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
            document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
        }

        // Called on form's `onsubmit`
        function tosubmit() {
            // Getting the value of your text input
            var mytext = document.getElementById("mytext").value;

            // Storing the value above into a cookie
            setCookie("mytext", mytext, 300);

            return true;
        }

    </script> 
</head>
<body>
    <center>   
        <!-- INLCUDING `ONSUBMIT` EVENT + ACTION URL --> 
        <form name="myform" onsubmit="tosubmit();" action="confirm.html">

            <input  id="mytext" type="text" name="data">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">

        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

`confirm.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

    // Function for retrieveing value from a cookie
    function getCookie(c_name)
    {
        var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
        for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
        {
            x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
            y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
            x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
            if (x==c_name)
            {
                return unescape(y);
            }
        }
    }

    // Called on body's `onload` event
    function init() {
        // Retrieving the text input's value which was stored into a cookie
        var mytext = getCookie("mytext");

        // Writing the value in the document
        document.write("passed value = "+mytext);
    }

</script>
</head>    

<body onload="init();">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: or cookies in any HTML version

Comment: WOW! Cookie is excellent idea but it is hard for me to 100% understand. I have another question, I don't know if I should create a new question or I can ask here. but assume I have more than one text field (such as LastName, FirstName, Email, Address...) I don't want same person (just validate Name and Email) can submit form more than 1 time, how could I validate it using cookie of course, still display all info or error message in confirm.html. Sorry if it too confuse I will create new question.

Comment: I mean if I enter a form 10 times using 10 different Names and Emails I will got 10 cookies RIGHT? so how can I verify if in 11th time I enter info exactly same as 1st time and confirm.html should display that "this user have already submit a form"????

Comment: @RonaldinhoState: Woh... I understood what you mean. In fact, you want to be able to identify each data that was submitted. In fact, usually, you may store data in database and then, when a user submits a form, we first check whether this user already submitted a form or not (we can trace him by email for example, since an email only belongs to one person). However, accessing database from javascript may not be a good solution (eg: security issues), and server side languages (eg: PHP) are preferred in this situation.

Comment: @RonaldinhoState: I suggest you ask this as another question, so that you'll get more advice. Anyway, make sure to define the accurate purpose of your app: who will use it, what data will you use, will there be security stuffs, what would be the size of stored data, etc?

Comment: Never mind the above question. Now I just want to add a validate that not allowing user to submit the form twice (no matter what they type in Name or Email or ...) until they close the browser and open again? Is there anyway to do that using cookie, in your code above, is cookie be removed if browser is close?

Comment: The cookies can be removed if they expired (cookies have a defined expiration date) or if you delete the history of your browser.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18027/discussion-between-ronaldinhostate-and-littm)

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is submit the form using a `get` method (`method="get"`), and send it to your `confirm.html` page (`action="./confirm.html"`).

Then, you could use jQuery to retrieve the values from the URL from your `confirm.html` page.

This website provides a method to do that: http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2012/06/get-url-parameters-using-jquery.html .

Then, all you have to do is call your `display()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Seams like a fit for [persist.js](https://github.com/jeremydurham/persist-js), which will let you save and load data in the user's browser. After including its javascript file, you can save data like this:

```
var store = new Persist.Store('My Application');
store.set('some_key', 'this is a bunch of persistent data');
```

And you can later retrieve the saved data in another html page like the following:

```
var store = new Persist.Store('My Application');
val = store.get('some_key');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also, instead of changing the page, change the content of the page. Upon submission just change the page using the innerHtml variable.

Comment: Please be more specific (ex: can you show some example code) since I really don't want to use cookie at this level, maybe next level in validation part I will need cookie but not now. Thanks!