# Working with cookie JavaScript HTML form

Tags: javascript, cookies

As continuation from that question: [JavaScript display new page when submit HTML form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887702/javascript-display-new-page-when-submit-html-form/12889531#12889531)

with accepted answer from Littm (using Cookie)

now I want that if cookie is existing the confirm.html will display "Sorry you can't submit the form twice", if it is not then display cookie as normal.

Any IDEA is really appreciated?

Comment: Could you re post the whole code here please?

Comment: Please clarify your question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try this

```
function getCookie(c_name){
    var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++){
      x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
      y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
      x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
      if (x==c_name){
        return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}

function checkCookie(cookie_name){
    var cookieName=getCookie(cookie_name);
    if (cookieName!=null && cookieName!=""){
        alert("Sorry you can't submit the form twice");
    } else {
      //your code
    }
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp