# How to save information from a text box and show it on another html page

Tags: html

i'm new to programing and im making a simple website using html and css.
I need a code so that i can type text into a text box, and have it appear on another page.
is this possible?

Comment: yes, it is possible. but too bad, stackoverflow is not the place where you can simply request for codes without showing any effort.

Comment: check the page in SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887702/javascript-display-new-page-when-submit-html-form

Comment: i can post my code if you want.

Comment: jsfiddle.net post your code there and give us a link, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look into `<form>` elements -- something like:

```
<form action="page-to-send-data-to" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="myText">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

However, you'd need to have the page receiving the data able to "GET" the information. If you're using PHP, you'd do:

```
echo $_GET['myText'];
```

to display the text you submitted in the first page.